# How can I use wp_query search for UK Postcodes with space and without space equally?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to make a `wp_query` who search UK Postcode with space and without space equally

```
$postcode = $_GET['postcode'];
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'architect',
    'post_status'  => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'  => 6,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'postcode',
        'value' => $postcode,
        'compare' => '='
        )
    )
);
```

Example `BT3 9DT` = `BT39DT`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do a `$postcode = str_replace( ' ', '', $_GET['postcode'] )`.

Should do the trick, unless you are storing the postcodes in the database with spaces. But I'd suggest that you do the same (replacing space with `''`) while storing the postcode in the database.

That way you are sure what you're getting out.